# Symfony - Error on deleting related entities

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with related entities while I wanna editing an entry. I have three entities that are  related together: User, Reporting, and reporting_freigabe.
When I create a  new Reporting, I can select users who can review my Reporting, and an  entry is created in reporting_freigabe with the status open.
This works so far. (Freigabe is something like review)
However, when  I edit the reporting and choose other users in the form, existing  entries in reporting_freigabe should be removed. However, when I try to  delete, I receive the following error:

An exception  occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint  violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key  constraint fails (`bkcwebdev_reporting`.`reporting_freigabe`, CONSTRAINT  `FK_9966B42427EE0E60` FOREIGN KEY (`reporting_id`) REFERENCES  `reporting` (`id`))
Do i have a problem with my entitys ? Hope somebody has a tip for me

My reporting entity:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReportingRepository::class)]
class Reporting
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $titel = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $beschreibung = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $inhalt = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'reportingsersteller')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $ersteller = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'reportings')]
    private ?Kategorie $kategorie = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'reporting', targetEntity: ReportingFreigabe::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], fetch: 'EAGER')]
    private Collection $reportingFreigabes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());
        $this->reportingFreigabes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    
    // GETTERS SETTERS .....


    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ReportingFreigabe>
     */
    public function getReportingFreigabes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->reportingFreigabes;
    }

    public function addReportingFreigabe(ReportingFreigabe $reportingFreigabe): static
    {
        if (!$this->reportingFreigabes->contains($reportingFreigabe)) {
            $this->reportingFreigabes->add($reportingFreigabe);
            $reportingFreigabe->setReporting($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeReportingFreigabe(ReportingFreigabe $reportingFreigabe): static
    {
        if ($this->reportingFreigabes->removeElement($reportingFreigabe)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($reportingFreigabe->getReporting() === $this) {
                $reportingFreigabe->setReporting(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Entity for my "freigabes"

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ReportingFreigabeRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReportingFreigabeRepository::class)]
class ReportingFreigabe
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'reportingFreigabes')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Reporting $reporting = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'reportingFreigabes', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], fetch: 'EAGER')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $benutzer = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Choice(choices: ['offen', 'erledigt'])]
    private ?string $status = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setStatus('offen');
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getReporting(): ?Reporting
    {
        return $this->reporting;
    }

    public function setReporting(?Reporting $reporting): static
    {
        $this->reporting = $reporting;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBenutzer(): ?User
    {
        return $this->benutzer;
    }

    public function setBenutzer(?User $benutzer): static
    {
        $this->benutzer = $benutzer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): static
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In the reporting Controller i check an array and releate "freigabes" with

```
$reporting->removeReportingFreigabe($buffFreigabe);
```

I checked different relations

Comment: _"I unfortunately have a new problem"_. What other problem you had? This is the first question you post.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry. My other problem wasn't related to this one. I had problems with two entities that had two many-to-many relationships, and they were conflicting with each other

Comment: But did you post a question about that other problem?

Comment: No, solved it by checking other posts but i corrected my post here

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve error from database but not from symfony application (doctrine to be more precise).

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (bkcwebdev_reporting.reporting_freigabe, CONSTRAINT FK_9966B42427EE0E60 FOREIGN KEY (reporting_id) REFERENCES reporting (id))
```

By this error, MySQL say's - you can't change (delete) row in table `reporting_freigabe` because this row contain reference to `reporting` table, and options `ON DELETE / ON UPDATE` not presented, as result MySQL don't know what do with row in `reporting` table.

Doctrine, by default (schema update, or migrations) do not add options `ON DELETE / ON UPDATE`. As result, you should modify you migration (or update schema manually) and add this option, what say's to MySQL what do with relation.

Previously, view you schema, with `SHOW CREATE TABLE reporting_freigabe`. After, you can modify foreign keys and ADD correct `ON DELETE / ON UPDATE` options.

For more info about constraint (foreign key), please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Hey ZhukV,

thank u for ur answer, but i still get the same error. 
I recreated the table with ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE for the Foreign key. Looks like:

`CREATE .. (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `IDX_9966B42427EE0E60` (`reporting_id`),
    KEY `IDX_9966B4249F9AC274` (`benutzer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_9966B42427EE0E60` FOREIGN KEY (`reporting_id`) REFERENCES `reporting` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_9966B4249F9AC274` FOREIGN KEY (`benutzer_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB ..`